# Plotly.js in relative barmode labels are overlapped when both bars have value 0

Tags: d3.js, plotly, plotly.js

Continue my journey with [Plotly.js](https://plotly.com/javascript/). I'm using [relative barmode](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-barmode) and need to show some customized text when both opposite bars have value `0`. The issue that for value 0 both bars grow in the same direction and labels are overlapped:
[image]

The only solution which I've thought about is checking when the value is `0` and change it dynamically to something like `-0.009` and manually display the right value despite it's actually wrong. But it's cumbersome solution and chart keep rendering tiny bar for those values which isn't acceptable.

[This is my example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anatoly314/pen/ExVQJxw)

Can label direction be controlled manually? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Initial Thoughts

One solution is to specify the base parameter for each trace as 0 and for the negative bars use a negative base value if the value is 0.

```js
      const altbase=-1000/3;

      const trace1 = {
        x: xValue,
        y: [FN],
        name: `Model 1`,
        text: `${FN} <br> FN`,
        type: 'bar',
        base: 0,
        textposition: 'outside'
      };
      const trace2 = {
        x: xValue,
        y: [-TN],
        name: 'Model 1',
        text: `${TN} <br> TN`,
        base: altbase,
        type: 'bar',
        textposition: 'outside'
      };
```

It looks like `-max_y_lim / 3` results in a good offset which is what `altbase` is used for.

You could also define `altbase` as a variable checking if TN==0:

```js
var altbase = ((TN==0) ? -FP/3 : 0);
```

UPDATE1: or you can bypass the variable and put the if statement right into trace definition like `base: ((TN==0) ? -FP/3 : 0),`

UPDATE2: and a slightly more elegant equation for the offset would be:

```js
var altbase = ((TN==0) ? -1.4/4*Math.max(FN,TN,TP,FP) : 0);
```

#### Final Update

After some thought it's probably best to always calculate `altbase` so that it's available to the other potential negative bar and then use an if statement for setting the `base:` where needed.

```js
      var altbase = -1.4/4*Math.max(FN,TN,TP,FP);

      const trace1 = {
        x: xValue,
        y: [FN],
        name: `Model 1`,
        text: `${FN} <br> FN`,
        type: 'bar',
        base: 0,
        textposition: 'outside'
      };
      const trace2 = {
        x: xValue,
        y: [-TN],
        name: 'Model 1',
        text: `${TN} <br> TN`,
        base: ((TN==0) ? altbase : 0),
        type: 'bar',
        textposition: 'outside'
      };
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/jayveesea/pen/mdejJvy) is the implementation in CodePen.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but something wrong with it. If I change a little bit numbers it doesn't work. Look at this codepen: https://codepen.io/anatoly314/pen/vYNzrKr

Comment: I realized that the two bar graphs are separate plots so calculating `altbase` based on all values does not always work.  Combining them into one plot with two bars would work.  Or a more simple calculation with the existing framework is [here at codepen](https://codepen.io/jayveesea/pen/ExVeGVq), BUT this only offsets the negative side if they are both zero.  Something like `base: ((TN==0 & FN==0) ? -.25 : 0)`

Comment: Also, [here](https://codepen.io/jayveesea/pen/xxwamgb) is an example with the two bars in one plot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I cannot accept it. It isn't easy to implement and I came to the conclusion that there isn't a good solution for this problem except to continue to talk with plotlyjs team and add a fix in the library itself. Actually I've opened an issue here:  https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4822 will try to arrange a fix and commit it. I apologise and thank you for your effort.